# Why is my zsh history file not being written after each event?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I have this in my .zshrc:

```
setopt -o sharehistory
HISTFILE=~/.histfile.$TTY:t
HISTSIZE=500
SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
```

My understanding of *sharehistory* is that this would cause the HISTFILE to be updated after each command. However, it is still written only when the shell exits.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, my mistake! I need one more option:

```
setopt -o incappendhistory
```

With this, it works.